# Preg_match triggering when it shouldn't

Tags: php

Okay, I'm using the following code (where `$password` = the post password variable). This is part of a large form validation code, and this line of code seems to trigger when it shouldn't. I'm afraid some part of it is deprecated. I've tried entering `pass123A`, `Password12`, and `1Password`, and they all trigger this code. Why?

```
elseif(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/", $password) == 0)
echo('Error - the password can only contain alpha-numeric chars!');
```

Comment: What does your question have to do with MySql?

Comment: That RegExp will only match one character. Try adding a "+" after "]" and remove unnecessary "^" and "$" for your particular case: /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/

Comment: *Why* are you constraining passwords like this?

Comment: I believe SQL cannot contain certain characters (like non-standard), so I wanted to avoid invalid characters being entered.

@DCoder

Comment: Stop that. [Sanitize user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) before passing it into SQL queries. Restricting input like you're doing is a tell-tale sign of amateur systems and a big red honking "easy target" sign for all the script kiddies.

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/", $password)
```

...will only match single character passwords.

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $password)
```

...should work better.

Maybe I should note that this will also match an *empty* password, but I assume that you check length separately.

EDIT: If you're restricting passwords due to SQL insecurities, you should really change over to PDO or MySQLi and use parameterized queries, that will allow you to store any string without special handling for special characters (like `'`), which will make SQL all over your site more secure.

Further, if you're storing passwords in clear text anyway, you should look into hashing them :)

Comment: As I said in a comment above, is that "^" really necessary? Just because if all accepted characters are alphanumeric, without a particular initial one, "^" is not necessary, isn't it? Note that I'm not saying it won't work, I want to know if that's necessary or not.

Comment: And a blank password! :)

Comment: @AlejandroIván If you remove the `^` and `$`, it will match anywhere in the string, not the whole string. In other words, `/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/` will match any string that has _any_ alphanumeric character in it. We want to match a string where _all_ characters are alphanumeric.

Comment: To show the difference, `echo preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", 'a!');
echo preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", 'a!');` will give a match on the latter, not what we want.

Comment: Yes, I have a check length, this is one of 4 checks on the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this: `+$`

```
if (...)
   // do anything
elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $password))
   echo('Error - the password can only contain alpha-numeric chars!');
```

Use `+$` instead of `*$`.

`*` allow empty string. If `$password` send as empty, not match.